# pytest: Dealing with C extensions exiting

Tags: python, c, linux, jenkins, pytest

While writing unit tests, I had a rather frustrating and painful experience debugging why pytest would prematurely exit and cut off output under Jenkins, but not when I ran it from my shell. It turns out an environment variable difference led some code deep in an external C extension to `exit()`.

While the reason for pytest's termination is clear:

- It (understandably) does not seem possible to prevent or detect such exiting with pytest
- It seems completely unfeasible to debug this as Jenkins runs

I'd like to keep this unit test, but it is scary having code that may cause undebuggable untestable nightmares down the road. Are there any tricks, strategies, or tools that can aid in dealing with such problems?

Comment: Have you attempted to catch the `SystemExit`? `SystemExit` inherits from `BaseException` rather than `Exception`. Catching `SystemExit` may cause other issues further down the road, but it's worth a try.

Comment: SystemExit nor anything Python-related seems to get triggered on exit(). I guess you're not supposed to `exit()` in a C extension, but when it's not your code...

Comment: Oh wow. I misunderstood. I figured the C extension's `exit()` triggered a `SystemExit`. That seems like a show stopper. Any chance you have the source for the C extension? You could fix the issue, or better yet, if it's published on github.com, etc. you can file an issue.

Comment: If opencv uses a GTK backend, it may occur here github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkmain.c#L634 and the warning is not displayed. GTK seems perfectly justified in using exit, opencv seems to have little choice in how it interfaces with GTK, although it seems unfortunate for things other than just pytest. It's seeming more like an inevitable thing that one must keep in mind, and maybe this question is too vague...

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. GTK will exit if there's no display because display is the whole point of GTK. Sounds like whatever you're doing with opencv requires a windowing system.